# Unable To Load Image in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, assets, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter. When i tried to load assets, i faced with an issue.

I checked pubspec.yaml file for identiation but i couldn't find any problem.

I checked the given path.

I also tried another images, even extension(.png,.jpg)

**This is the Exception:**

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/pink_flower.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
```

**This is .yaml file**

```
name: flutterproject
description: VFL Lisesi uygulaması flutter ile.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
    sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    
flutter:

uses-material-design: true

assets:
    - assets/images/flower2.png
    - assets/images/pink_flower.jpg

fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
    fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/montserrat_black.ttf
        weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/montserrat_black_italic.ttf
        weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/montserrat_bold.ttf
        weight: 600
    - family: Trajan Pro
    fonts:
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
```

**ImageWidget**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageBanner extends StatelessWidget {

final String _path;

ImageBanner(this._path);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
        height: 300.0,
    ),
    child: Image.asset(
        _path,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    );
}

}
```

**calling ImageWidget**

```
ImageWidget('assets/images/pink_flower.jpg')
```

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` and did a full restart?

Comment: Yes , i have just restarted and it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make changes to your `pubspec.yaml` file, make sure to perform these two steps afterwards.

1. Run `flutter pub get`.
2. Stop the ongoing session and do a full restart.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure your indentation is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

wrong indentation

fix:

```
assets:
  - assets/images/flower2.png
  - assets/images/pink_flower.jpg
```